# Have image open in its own page with information

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page with images on it. Each image has information associated with it, and when the image is clicked I'd like to have it open in its own page (not a new tab or window) with some of the associated information displayed around it.

Is there a way to do this where I don't have to manually make a page for each image? I'm dealing with a large set of pictures so automation is key.

Comment: Something like google's images perhaps?

Comment: When clicking an image have it expand and show some information about it to the right, while pushing the other images below or above? That sounds acceptable. What is your suggestion?

Comment: take a look at this [link from cordrops](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2014/03/21/google-grid-gallery/)

Comment: @CanIHaveSomeChange , I would suggest this : http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/03/19/thumbnail-grid-with-expanding-preview/

Comment: The information looks absent from the picture when it's displayed.

Comment: I think all gallery/lightbox scripts do exactly this. Open a zoomed in version of the image and add some meta data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ? info could be moved around , styled as per needs.

```css
.info{display:none}
img:hover +.info{display:inline;}
```

```html
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"width="150" height="150" />
<span class="info">This pic is super</span>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"width="150" height="150" />
<span class="info">This pic is super</span>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"width="150" height="150" />
<span class="info">This pic is super</span>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"width="150" height="150" />
<span class="info">This pic is super</span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"width="150" height="150" />
<span class="info">This pic is super</span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"width="150" height="150" />
<span class="info">This pic is super</span><img src="http://lorempixel.com/150/150"width="150" height="150" />
<span class="info">This pic is super</span>*emphasized text*
```